# Unrecognized config option "url_generator"

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony-cmf

I'm currently working on an application involving the dynamic router. To customise the url generator I followed the documentation [found here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/routing/dynamic_customize.html#using-a-custom-url-generator). Unfortunately it doesn't work, the following exception occurs:

```
InvalidConfigurationException in ArrayNode.php line 312:

Unrecognized option "url_generator" under "cmf_routing.dynamic"
```

This is the relevant part of my `config.yml`:

```
# CMF Routing Configuration
cmf_routing:
    cmf_routing:
        routers_by_id:
            router.default: 200
            cmf_routing.dynamic_router: 100
    dynamic:
        enabled: true
        route_provider_service_id: collab.routing.route_provider
        url_generator: collab.routing.url_generator
```

and for reference, this is the part of `services.yml`:

```
collab.routing.route_provider:
    class: CollaborationBundle\Routing\RouteProvider
    arguments:
        - "@annotation_reader"
        - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
        - "@module.provider"
collab.routing.url_generator:
    class: CollaborationBundle\Routing\UrlGenerator
```

What is the right way to use a custom url generator?

Comment: I think the documentation is wrong here. From looking at the code it looks like this option was not part of any stable release yet.

Comment: Fixing the documentation to add which version adds the feature: https://github.com/symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf-docs/pull/727

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is only available in version 1.4 of RoutingBundle, which is not yet released. You can already start to use it with

```
symfony-cmf/routing-bundle: 1.4.*@dev
```

The release should happen in the next days, and we don't expect many changes for 1.4 anymore, so this should be pretty safe.